# Weird behavior of UIView frame after rotation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uikit, frame, cgaffinetransform

Create a square UIView object testView_, and add this at viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
CGRect initialRect = testView_.frame;
NSLog(@"before rotation: w %f h %f x %f y %f", initialRect.size.width, initialRect.size.height, initialRect.origin.x, initialRect.origin.y);
testView_.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.1);
NSLog(@"after rotation: w %f, h %f, x %f, y %f", testView_.frame.size.width, testView_.frame.size.height, testView_.frame.origin.x, testView_.frame.origin.y);
testView_.frame = initialRect;
NSLog(@"reassign: w %f, h %f, x %f, y %f", testView_.frame.size.width, testView_.frame.size.height, testView_.frame.origin.x, testView_.frame.origin.y);
}
```

I receive this in the console:

```
2011-04-27 12:30:32.492 Test[31890:207] before rotation: w 100.000000 h 100.000000 x 20.000000 y 20.000000
2011-04-27 12:30:32.494 Test[31890:207] after rotation: w 109.483757, h 109.483757, x 15.258121, y 15.258121
2011-04-27 12:30:32.495 Test[31890:207] reassign: w 117.873589, h 100.000000, x 11.063205, y 20.000000
```

I couldn't figure out the logic behind this change in frame value, especially the last one. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: I am not completely sure about this answer. So I am putting it as a comment..When we rotate a view, say B, which is a subView of A, only the transform of B gets changed. Frame is considered in terms of ones position in parentView, ie B's position in A.

So when we rotate B, the total square space (calculated in A's transform) B took in A, increases. That is the reason for second log..Now third you forcefully give original frame to B, but rotated B now has size than original size which forces parentView A to autoadjust B by keeping only one direction (y and height / x and width) constant.

Comment: good question though..I would like to know too..

Comment: you got no answer...too bad..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In UIView Class Reference you can see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) that you should not set the frame of a view with transform property different than **CGAffineTransformIdentity**.

If you want to change the position of the transformed view, you should use **center** property. If you want to adjust the size you should use **bounds** property.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I solved this by first setting `view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`, then setting the frame, and then setting the rotation with `view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);`

Comment: @Liron This doesn't seem to work any longer.  The frame has issues.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This post is pretty old, so I'm not sure if I really remember what this was all about. In most cases these days, I find it easier to use auto-layout than to manually assign the frame - but of course it depends on the application.

Comment: @Liron Am working on older code where autolayout makes no sense.  Anyhow, in the code the order is right and used to work, now it doesn't.  Frame randomly likes to change.